# Request content for uploading local csv file's data to BigQuery tables

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

Instantiating HttpWebRequest and setting properties values:-

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/776934660156/jobs");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "multipart/related; boundary=xxx";
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + strAccessToken);//Service Account Access token
```

Below is the content of HttpWebRequest object. When i pass this request i get an error 400 bad request:-

```
--xxx
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
"kind" : "bigquery#job" ,
"Id" : "testJob" ,
"configuration": {
"load": {
"destinationTable": {
"projectId": "776934660156",
"datasetId": "BMSTestDataset",
"tableId": "tblEvents"
},
"fieldDelimiter":"|", 
}
}
}
--xxx
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
ET00000102|MT|50|Hindi|Halla Bol|2008-01-11 00:00:00|0|2007-08-07 15:51:38.240000000|<Genre><code>DRAMA</code></Genre>|<Legends><Actor>83</Actor><Actor>2457</Actor><Actor>1639</Actor><Actor>1151</Actor><Actor>1717</Actor><Actor>1526</Actor><Director>1801</Director><Music>820</Music></Legends>
ET00000103|MT|50|Hindi|Kisse Pyaar Karoon|2009-02-27 00:00:00|0|2007-08-07 17:16:36.443000000|<Genre><code>DRAMA</code></Genre>|<Legends><Actor>228</Actor><Actor>46</Actor><Actor>2539</Actor><Actor>2415</Actor><Actor>44</Actor><Actor>2161</Actor><Actor>2100</Actor><Director>82</Director><Music>2624</Music></Legends>
--xxx--
```

I didn't specify schema because the table already exists in BQ dataset. Please help me out, I did a lot of research, but not getting any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

First, the BigQuery Load configuration should look like this (note the newlines after the Content-type header:

```
--xxx
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  'configuration': {
    'load': {
      // Schema, only if necessary
      'schema': {
        'fields': [
          {'name':'f1', 'type':'STRING'},
          {'name':'f2', 'type':'INTEGER'}
        ]
      },
      'destinationTable': {
        'projectId': 'projectId',
        'datasetId': 'datasetId',
        'tableId': 'tableId'
      }
    }
  }
}
--xxx
```

Also, if you want to set the Job ID use the jobReference.jobId parameter (see the BigQuery API [load config documentation)](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#importing). Example:

```
"jobReference": {
    "jobId": 'SOMESTRINGHERE'
}
```

P.S. I think it's good practice to use a random boundary string, such as:

```
var boundary = "------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there any issue in the way i'm passing multipart/related content type and authorization to request object?